# Select/option value equivalent to java?

Tags: java, html, swing, jcombobox

I know that for a select menu on html we have

```
<option> value='nr/string..etc'>NameOfOption</option>
```

How can I make a similar select menu in java?

I know that I need to use JComboBox but all I can found is that I can add String to the list,
but the problem pops up when I fill it using mysql data since I would want to get the primary key(ID) from the selectedItem.

A simple java JComboBox would be something like:

```
String[] lcateg={"string1","string2","string3","string4"};
         categorie=new JComboBox(lcateg);
         add(categorie);
```

Hope it is clear what I want and sorry if something similar was asked(and if it was asked please point me to it),but I did not now how to search it on search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Combo Box With Hidden Data](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/combo-box-with-hidden-data/) for one approach.

The other approach is to use a custom renderer. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Providing a Custom Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) for more information. Just note that this approach will remove the ability to select and item from the combo box by using the first letter of the item name.